# Hotspot not working after root attempt

Tags: rooting, stock-android, wifi-hotspot

I have a Motorola Moto G 3-TE with Android 6.0.1, Few weeks back I thought of rooting it and tried several methods. I tried using Kingroot app from my phone and also tried **KingoRoot** from PC. My fault was that my pc was connected to the same device's Hotspot. Although my phone restarted few times, the root attempt failed and unfortunately my phone's Hotspot stopped working. Everything else is working fine. I just want a way to repair my phone's Mobile Hotspot. Please Help

Comment: have you tried a factory reset, or wiping the data and cache from the the WiFi related apps.  I have tried this before as well, i thought that the programme would download all required files for rooting first. but it works much like the application, downloading as it goes ! ... Nearly all king root installs that say failed, actually worked, but the application ( KingUser ) failed to download or install, after it has gained temporary root access and already leveraged the .ku file into system/bin/ku/... Which means it has successfully installed the super user binary for kinguser.

Comment: Rooting has this great disadvantage: it makes the phone a guinea-pig, and data and system processes might be lost or malfunction after a rooting process.